# MVC3 get Select Box Option Name as Well as Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-interface, drop-down-menu

```
     <select id="selectedSchool" size="3" multiple="multiple" name="selectedSchool"> 
   @foreach (var item in ViewBag.pt)
   {


  <OPTION VALUE="@item.entityID">@item.name</OPTION>
   }
    </select>
```

on my page the user selects a school from the list of schools, each school has a unique ID which is needed and passed via the VALUE attribute, I also would like to pick up the name
(item.name) that was selected how can I resolve this info from my control Action Result?

```
     public ActionResult ResultsSchoolsAttended(List<int> selectedSchool)
```

i iterate through the list of results, but I would aslo like selectedSchool.name to enter back in the db as 'display text'

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, MVC can only give you what is in the HTTP POST. And if you look at that, you will see that the `<option>` inner HTML isn't there. So you have only two choices:

1. Include it in the `value` in your markup, or
2. Look it up in your `ResultsSchoolsAttended` action based on the submitted value.

I'd pick the second, personally.

Comment: Did it the Hidden field way, used a little JS and added selected options to a hidden field, captured that in the post of my actionresult.